# Loading data frame to mysql in R Programming

Tags: r

I have this code and want to read and insert all the data in the data frame to mysql but I'm getting this error:

```
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘dbWriteTable’ for signature ‘"MySQLConnection", "character", "tbl_myr"’
```

My database is up and running and df1 is my data that I want to insert.
Is there anything I'm doing wrong?

```
> mydb = dbConnect(MySQL(), user='test', password='passwd', dbname='test_db', host='192.168.1.77')
> dbWriteTable(mydb, value =df1, name ="test_db.myr" , row.names = F , append = T , overwrite = F )
```

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: What does `class(df1)` show you?

Comment: Typing ?class(df1) does not print anything...it just shows me documentation on class in the Help tab  on RStudio

Comment: This is strange.  R should tell you that `df1` is a data frame.  That being said, is `df1` actually a data frame?

Comment: I think so. Here is what I'm doing to load my file onto Rstudio:  mydata = read.csv("C:\\Users\\helen\\Desktop\\output.csv")  and the data is available when i simply type mydata

Comment: Are you sure the column names in the table match those in the `df1` data.frame? You should have same number of fields in both the database table and the data.frame. Also the names have to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are reading in your data as a data frame named mydata. So your code to import the data to sql should be:

```
mydb = dbConnect(MySQL(), user='test', password='passwd', dbname='test_db', host='192.168.1.77')
# NOTICE that value = df1 CHANGED to value = mydata since your data frame is actually named mydata. 
dbWriteTable(mydb, value = mydata, name ="test_db.myr" , row.names = F , append = T , overwrite = F )
```

running class(mydata) should result in data.frame.

Comment: I think I know what the problem might be. Although I was able to load an excel file - and managed to query it on RStudio, it was not actually a data frame. Renaming the file on my desktop from .xlsx to csv was all it took. What if I wanted to make an excel into a dataframe, how does that work?